# Find common ratio with two terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

I am trying to find common ratio but ...

If $b_1 = -2$ and $b_8 = -384$, how can I find common ratio (q)?

Comment: **Hint:** $\frac {b_8}{b_1} = q^7$. Also, please try defining $b_n$ in advance. I assume it means term number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're asking for a *common ratio* probably means that the sequence with terms $b_n$ form a **geometric sequence** but that's something you should mention. It also helps to show your own effort, ideas or relevant formulas you have seen.

You probably know that $b_n = q \cdot b_{n-1}$ and from this also $b_n = q^{n-1}\cdot b_1$. You know $b_1$ and $b_8$ so use this formula with $n=8$ to get an equation for $q$.

Comment: And if I know that b2 = 7 and b5 = 56

Comment: Does this formula help me? I think no. Am I wrong?

Comment: Then you either work your way backwards and go via $b_1$ (formula above), or you could think a bit longer/harder and come up with a direct relation between $b_2$ and $b_5$. It's not that hard: $b_3=q\cdot b_2$ so $b_4 = \ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For a geometric progression with first term $a$ and common ratio $r$, the $n^{\text{th}} $ term is given by: $$b_n = ar^{n-1}$$

Here, $b_1 =a=-2$ and $b_8 = - 384$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think the OP would prefer $b_n$ to $T_n$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $b_n = b_0 q^{n}$. Compute $b_8 / b_1$.